# Easiest way to keep SSRS child elements in the same relative position when the parent is re-positioned?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to revise the layout of an SSRS report where I have several textboxes that are child elements of a rectangle.

When I reposition the parent rectangle down by x, all of the child textboxes maintain the same absolute position.  Their "Location" (defined relative to the parent) decreases by x. I then need to reposition the child textboxes.  Additionally, if any of these ever has a negative "Location" then the parent rectangle is then repositioned back up by x.

What is the easiest way to move everything in unison?  I can Control-click everything and then drag them or use the arrow keys, but I want to position everything with precision and the "Location" field in the Properties window disappears when selecting more than one item.  Is there a way I can avoid individually computing and typing in every "Location" value every time I have a small layout change?

I am using SSRS (11.0.3360.12) within the Visual Studio 2012 Shell.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having the exact same issue as you. I'd swear this used to work properly in earlier versions of Visual Studio.

The only thing I've seen that works is to edit the report file's xml directly in a text editor. e.g. look for the rectangle's element, then hand edit the value of "Top". Back in visual studio, let the report reload. Things should be ok, as long as you picked a reasonable value for "Top".

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  Thank you!  That would've saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

The only other available option to track position is by enabling ruler. Report -> View -> Ruler

Comment: Thank you for your response!  This is relevant, but doesn't really solve my main problem, which is that SSRS needlessly changes the "Location" property of child elements when the parent is moved, breaking my layout.